# Is there On Error Resume Label in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there On Error Resume Label in Excel VBA? If the answer is no, how come?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. See below:

```
Sub Whatever()
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    '...

Leave:
    On Error Resume Next
     'Clean up
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it a good habit to also include error handlers in the cleanup/resetting section of the program after you handled regular errors in the `ErrProc`? I mean you also use `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` in the label `Leave`.

Comment: Yes, it's good practice to reset the error handling in VBA before exiting the sub `On Error GoTo 0`. As for the `On Error Resume Next` - this is a personal preference as some objects references might be invalid when you try to clear them, e.g. `rs.Close` (Recorset) or `doc.Close` (Word).

Comment: 1. But if you used `On Error Resume Next`, you might think everything is cleared up when it's not. On the other hand, you can always locate the exact line that triggers the error (for example, which object cannot be referenced) with the debugger if you don't add `On Error Resume Next`. 2. As for the `On Error GoTo 0`, once you exits `Whatever`, the VBA will just resume its normal error-checking behavior (correct me if I am wrong), basically, you don't need to worry that `On Error Resume Next` in `Leave` will affect the error handling setting in the sub that calls` Whatever`.

Comment: Maybe I used the wrong term. Not clear, but close e.g. `rs.Close - Set rs.Nothing`. If `rs` is not open it throws an error (Set to Nothing does not throw an error even if the object is null). Again, this is a personal preference as I faced this a number of times especially with word documents in a loop. As for the `On Error GoTo 0` this is mostly for multiple procedures (where A calls B and B calls C) as VBA uses the last On Error statement to direct code execution.